# On hover tag search (i) icon is doubled up on itself

Tags: bug, tags, new-nav

When searching for tags to add to the homepage tab bar, the info link icon is doubled up on itself.

Repro in Chrome 50, Firefox 46, and Edge 25.10586.0.0.

Example:

[image: doubled up info mark, still happening :)]

Comment: Lack of caffeine can do shocking things to your brain. Thanks :)

Comment: Repro in Safari 9.1